# Android color codes not working?

Tags: android

I am trying to get this light blue background color for a View and it comes out to be grey .I dont understand why. the following is the hex color code which I got using Color cop:

http://www.color-hex.com/color/303d4d#

```
sm.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#303d4d"));
```

Thanks.

Comment: The color you linked to is not light blue.. Show code and we can tell you if you are using colors correctly.

Comment: Its kind of a blue but what I get is like a grey.. I have added code

Comment: its not really an answer to your question but in case you want a light blue, check out #edf8ff. I love it ;-)

Comment: your code is fine.. so I'm guessing your issue is with perception of the rendered color.. subtle color changes will happen from phone to phone based on variations in screen technology, configuration and age. If it just looks a little off, its probably your screen's fault.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Justin said, the color code you're referring to is not really blue or looks grayish.. Here is the proof:
[image]

The blue color will be something like "#187af2":
[image]

Comment: Okey, but I want that color code and I am getting grey... To me it looks lind of like a dark blue.. but I dont care what it is.. I am looking to get that color..

Comment: whats your problem? it looks like a dark blue to you, actually is grey though. as you can see in @M_Ys picture, its only 'almost' blue.